# Pushing mutlivalue entries into array with swift

Tags: swift

I have this code

```
    swiftAddressBook?.requestAccessWithCompletion({ (success, error) -> Void in
        if success {
            if let people = swiftAddressBook?.allPeople {
                for person in people {
                    println(person.phoneNumbers?.map( {$0.value} ))
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            //no success. Optionally evaluate error
        }
    })
```

Basically I would like to take each phone number and push it into an array.

The above code outputs:

```
Optional(["+11111111111"])
Optional(["+11111111111"])
Optional(["(111) 111-111"])
Optional([" (111) 111-111"])
Optional(["+11111111111", "+11111111111", "+11111111111", "+11111111111", "+11111111111", "+11111111111", "+11111111111", "+11111111111", "+11111111111", "+11111111111", "+11111111111", "+11111111111"])
Optional(["+11111111111"])
Optional(["+11111111111"])
Optional(["(111) 111-111"])
```

Im curious about 2 things. What can I add to my for loop to make each number added to my own array. Also, why is one Optional have like 50 numbers in it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you only want an array of non-optional phone numbers, and are happy to throw away any nil phone numbers (possibly this can never happen and the SwiftAddressBook code just needs to eliminate this optionality and only return empty arrays which would be much better):

```
        if success {
            var numbers: [String] = []

            if let people = swiftAddressBook?.allPeople {
                for person in people {
                    if let personNumbers = person.phoneNumbers {
                        numbers += personNumbers.map { number in
                            number.value
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            // numbers is an array of all the numbers in the address book
            println(numbers)
        }
```

The reason one optional has multiple numbers in it is pretty straightforward when you think abut an address book – people can have multiple phone numbers, so `person.phoneNumbers` returns an array.  You’re extracting the “value” property but there’s also a “label” property (for home, work, mobile etc).

Comment: Thank you for your first answer, but your second explanation can't be correct. I deleted many of the values in the output provided above. One Optional had literally 75 numbers or so. This is pulling from my addressbook on my phone and I know that one contact does not have 75 numbers such as mobile, home, ect.

Comment: Sure, whatever – I’m not familiar with the library in question (I glanced at it on github) but it seems pretty likely this is what’s happening.  But nonetheless, the reason there are multiple numbers is because personNumbers is returning an array (hence the square brackets in the output), and arrays can have multiple numbers.  Try printing out more properties, for example change `number.value` to be `"\(number.label): \(number.value)"`

Comment: Ya you were right. Thank you. When I added the label part one array had a ton of numbers with the label of "Powered by Truecaller." Where as the others just say <Mobile>

Comment: So the out put is now [[(111) 111-111], [+1111111111]]. How can i just get [+1111111111, +11111111111] so that each number is not in its own array

Comment: if let people = swiftAddressBook?.allPeople {
            for person in people {
                if let personNumbers = person.phoneNumbers {
                    personNumbers.map {
                        number in number.value
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
        println(arrayOfPhoneNumbers)


This is putting each number is its own array.

Comment: If I use your exact script it states 'Array<U>' is not convertible to 'String' on the personNumbers.map